# I can't pass id value into URL (modal Bootstrap) - another function

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, get, modal-dialog

I have a problem passing the "editar value from url..I use a Bootstrap - Twitter

this is the code:(a php file) ..

```
<a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" href="?editar='.$data["id_app"].'#editarModal"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
```

i saw the value in the bar (mean this is working).
But when i tried to get the value in another page..

```
$valor=intval($_GET['editar']);
$response = $bdd->query('Select * From appointment Where id_app="$valor"');
```

Doesn't work...

Thanks for your help!!!!!!!

Comment: What did you see when you echo $valor?

Comment: the problem apparently is the modal.....

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not interpolated in single quoted string in php

change

```
$response = $bdd->query('Select * From appointment Where id_app="$valor"');
```

to

```
$response = $bdd->query("Select * From appointment Where id_app='$valor'");
```

Assuming `$valor = 1` Your first attempt would result in the query string

```
Select * From appointment Where id_app="$valor"
```

whereas the second the variables will be interpolated and the db will get

```
Select * From appointment Where id_app='1'
```

Comment: The problem is not about $response. The thing is i can't get the $valor from $_GET['editar']

Comment: view source on the form and see what the href for the link is.

Comment: this is the url when you hover the botton http://192.168.1.200/app/appointment.php?editar=15#editarModal

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but if you are trying to load a remote page into your bootstrap modal (using the `href` attribute on a `data-toggle='modal'` link will do this), you have two issues:

1) You're missing a reference to the modal you want to open, it should be specified like this: `data-target='#modal-id'`

2) The URL in your `href` attribute needs to be a full URL and not relative, for bootstrap to load in content.

Comment: I used data-target and work fine only to open the modal form. in the second point mean that i can't use values ( ?editar=...).

Comment: You just need to specify the whole URL that you want loaded into the modal...like http://www.yoursite.com/foo.php?editar=1

Comment: this is the url when you hover the botton http://192.168.1.200/app/appointment.php?editar=15#editarModal

Comment: if i change the position in the url like this http://192.168.1.200/app/appointment.php?#editarModaleditar=15 didn't open the modal